How to assign values from vector to matrix in Matlab
Suppose we have matrix of indices A=[1,3;2,1] and array/cell array/struct/table of values

B=[10,20,30] or B=[10;20;30]
C={'aa';5;"g"}
D is 3x1 or 1x3 struct array with fields: values and D(ii).values is 1x1 numeric array. vertcat(D.values)=[21;22;23]

I want to get new array/cell array/string array with same size as A and filled with values from B,C, or D from the postions given in A

b=foo(A,B) returns b=[10,30;20,10]
c=bar(A,C) returns c={'aa',"g";5,'aa'}
d=foobar(A,D.values) returns d=[21,23;22,21]

I can do it with for loops but with arrays of 2000x2000 it is terribly inefficient. Is there a way to approach it faster?

For the first two cases, you can directly use A to index in your vector B or you cell array C, i.e., b = B(A), and c = C(A). For the last one, it's a bit trickier as you'll have to reshape your output, i.e., d=reshape([D(A).values],size(A))

You can just use A for indexing, the output array will be the same shape as the indexing array:
A=[1,3;2,1]; B=[10,20,30]; C={'aa';5;"g"};

b = B(A);
c = C(A);

You can handle d the same way as b if you make an intermediate array from D(:).values:
d = [D(:).values];
d = d(A);

Or do it directly as suggested by Bill in the comments, but you have to reshape because the shape isn't preserved when indexing a structure
d = reshape( [D(A).values], size(A) );


